# What is the difference between \u and \U in GNU sed

Tags: bash, sed, command-line, command

I come across these two commands `\u` and `\U` (and others such as `\l` and `\L`) in sed. I have to admit I am a newbie and have little experience with GNU sed.
I have tried the following two commands but got the same result:

```
# I have tested this on Ubuntu 20.04
echo "abc" | sed 's/./\u&/g' # output is: ABC
echo "abc" | sed 's/./\U&/g' # output is: ABC
```

The output is the same for the two commands. So, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Change `.` to `.*` on the LHS of the substitutiion and see the difference. Also lose the `g` flag.

Answer (score 5):

In a substitution replacement, `\u` converts the next character to uppercase, whereas `\U` converts the rest of the replacement to uppercase, or until `\L` or `\E` occurs.

Your example will not show the difference between them, because you are only replacing one character at a time. If you use the pattern `.*` (instead of `.`) in `echo abc | sed 's/.*/\u&/'`, you will get `Abc`.

The commands are documented in `info sed`, and here: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

Comment: @OK-Validation I did not down vote your question. It may have been down voted because it's less a programming question and more a "how does this program work?" question that belongs on Super User. Although personally I think that this line is less clear when it comes to shell programming.

Comment: Whether you accept the answer is entirely up to you. I don't know how I can be more clear other than to say `.` matches a single character, but `.*` will match every character. If you try `'s/.*/\u&/'` you will get `Abc`. Also note that `g` means _repeat_ the substitution for each occurrence of the pattern in the line. Perhaps `echo abc | sed 's/./\u&_/g'` would be illustrative. It prints `A_B_C_`.

Comment: @OK-Validation dan's answer is crystal clear, in my opinion. I cannot imagine anything that could improve it.